# set available dates in jquery datepicker to green color?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I try to make available dates in my datepicker green.
Sofar I managed to change the color to green for ALL dates. While the available dates are darker green I would rather set the unavailable to gray. How can I accomplish that? Below is my code.

JS:

```
    $(function() {
        var availableDates = ["9-5-2017","14-5-2017","15-5-2017"];

        function available(date) {
            dmy = date.getDate() + "-" + (date.getMonth()+1) + "-" + date.getFullYear();
            if ($.inArray(dmy, availableDates) != -1) {
                return [true, "","Available"];
            } else {
                return [false,"","unAvailable"];
            }
        }

        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
            firstDay: 1,
            dayNamesMin: ['Sö', 'Må', 'Ti', 'On', 'To', 'Fr', 'Lö'],
            beforeShowDay: available
        });
    });
```

CSS:

```
.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    color: green;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

Edit: partial solution in function available (it only changes the borders):

```
return [true, "availableStyle","Available"];
// CSS
.availableStyle {
    background: green !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this css rule:

```
.ui-state-disabled .ui-state-default {
    color: black;
    background: white;
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/jds6Lb3x/